# Negative Voltage Breakers?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, fuses

I've been reading a bit on negative voltage, but I have a question that will probably reveal some ignorance, so I apologize ahead of time.  If someone tells me that they want a (2) 5A breakers, (1) for a +24 circuit and (1) for a -48 circuit, would the same 5A, 80V breaker work for each?  As I understand negative voltage, it's just relative to an arbitrary ground point, so if a piece of dual voltage telecom equipment is pushing out +24V and -48V, wouldn't that breaker be good for each?  Or am I missing something basic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have the basic idea correct.  Just be sure that 80 volt rating is for DC, and not AC.  It does matter.  DC circuits are more difficult to break than AC.

Answer (score 3):

A thermally-activated mechanical circuit breaker would generally care nothing about the polarity of the current being switched.  An electromagnetically-activated one might care about polarity, but if it simply has two terminals which connect in-line with the current being switched, one could connect it in such a way as to be usable for high-side or low-side switching.

The only place I would expect trouble would be with breakers that contain integrated electronics.  Such devices may be limited to sensing and interrupting high-side or low-side currents.  I doubt that's what you're using, but such things exist (and can be useful in some situations since they can offer more precisely-controllable sensitivity).

Comment: I suppose the giveaway clue would be polarity markings on the breaker.